# How to calculate the sum of each position of subarrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Now my array is:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[]]
```

I want to calculate this array and return a result as:

```
[5,7,9]
```

If there is a null array, remove it. Then plus every position for each sub array.

If use array's each method, maybe I can get the result. But is there a better way just use ruby's array method?

Comment: Consider the sequence 2, 3, 3, 5, 10, 13, 39. What is the next number in the sequence? That's what this problem reminds me of. Where did `5`, `7` and `9` come from? And what does "plus every position for each sub array" mean? (Edit: I see, 1+4=5, 2+5=7, 3+6=9.) And how is this generalized to larger arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another one liner

```
arr.reject(&:empty?).transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

first get rid of the `[]`

```
reject(&:empty?)                           # equivalent to reject{|x| x.empty?}
```

now `.transpose` to obtain

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Add up each sublist with

```
.map{|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner that uses a lot of nice Ruby `Array` methods like `reject`, `reduce`, `zip`, and `map`.

```
array.reject(&:empty?).reduce { |result, e| result.zip(e).map { |x,y| x+y } }
```

See Ruby `Array` [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) for more details, and to see what other slick things you can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[]]

require 'matrix'

Matrix[*array.reject { |a| a.empty? }].row_vectors.reduce(:+).to_a
  #=> [5, 7, 9]
```